# Getting Dictionary<K,V> from ConcurrentDictionary<K,V> in .NET 4.0

Tags: collections, concurrency, dictionary, .net-4.0, parallel-processing

I'm parallelizing some back-end code and trying not to break interfaces.  We have several methods that return Dictionary and internally, I'm using ConcurrentDictionary to perform Parallel operations on.

What's the best way to return Dictionary from these?

This feels almost too simple:

```
return myConcurrentDictionary.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);
```

I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Constructing the `Dictionary<K,V>` directly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/et0ke8sz.aspx) will be *slightly* more efficient than calling `ToDictionary`. The constructor will pre-allocate the target dictionary to the correct size and won't need to resize on-the-fly as it goes along.

```
return new Dictionary<K,V>(myConcurrentDictionary);
```

If your `ConcurrentDictionary<K,V>` uses a custom `IEqualityComparer<K>` then you'll probably want to [pass that into the constructor too](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132073.aspx).

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Good info!

Comment: Will that work if items are added to or removed from the dictionary while the new dictionary is being constructed?

Comment: @supercat: Yep, that's fine. *"The enumerator returned from the dictionary is safe to use concurrently with reads and writes to the dictionary, however it does not represent a moment-in-time snapshot of the dictionary. The contents exposed through the enumerator may contain modifications made to the dictionary after `GetEnumerator` was called."* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287131.aspx

Comment: Is there any guarantee that an item which is deleted and re-added during enumeration will not create a key collision when constructing the new dictionary?

Comment: @supercat: I'm no expert, but I'm pretty sure that there are no guarantees. I'd expect some sort of runtime exception if I tried to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. This is completely fine. .NET sequences are just nice like that. :D